# How to add a tooltip to a single header from a list of headers in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a tooltip for only a single header (the one with the value 'Retire') but for none of the other headers.

This has been a long journey. I am new with Vue and thus have allied with the AI species (chatgpt) which has helped me somewhat. Now I am at the point where my front shows no errors, the browser shows no errors but no tooltip is shown. Can anyone help me achieve this? Thanks

This is the snippet of code where I am creating the data table and setting the headers as it looks at the moment.

```
<v-data-table
  class="zebrastripes"
  :items="autofilterItems"
  :items-per-page="20"
  :footer-props="{
  'items-per-page-options': [5, 10, 20, -1],
  }"
  :headers="headers"
  :search="search"
  :no-results-text="$t('General.noSearchMatch')"
  :custom-sort="dateSorting"
  :loading="trigger_loader"
  >
  <template v-slot:header="header">
    <th :key="header.text">
      <v-tooltip :value="header.value === 'Retire'" bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <span v-on="on">{{header.text}}</span>
        </template>
        <span v-if="header.value === 'Retire'">{{ header.tooltip }}</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </th>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: `<v-tooltip  v-if="header.value === 'Retire'" ...` ? If this doesn't work, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem, because other parts that weren't shown may affect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header.value` slot on each header item and apply a condition to show the tooltip only for specific headers.

Here is an example that is working with tooltips. You will see that the tooltip would only be displayed for a header with the title `Retire`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="autofilterItems"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1"
          :items-per-page="20"
          no-results-text="General.noSearchMatch"
          >
          <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ header }">
          <v-tooltip bottom v-if="header.value == 'Retire'">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <span v-on="on">{{ header.text }}</span>
            </template>
            <span>{{ header.tooltip }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <span v-else>{{ header.text }}</span>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-QTnb9BQkG4fBYIt9JGvYmxPpd6TBeKp6lsUrtiVQsrJ9sb33Bn9s0wMQO9qVBFbPX3xHRAsBHvXlcsrnJjExjg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {
          return {
            headers: [
              {
                text: 'Retire',
                value: 'Retire',
                sortable: false,
                tooltip: 'I am a tooltip'
              },
              {
                text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                value: 'name',
                sortable: false,
              },
              {
                text: 'Fat (g)',
                value: 'fat',
                sortable: false,
              },
              {
                text: 'Carbs (g)',
                value: 'carbs',
                sortable: false,
              },
              {
                text: 'Protein (g)',
                value: 'protein',
                sortable: false,
              },
              {
                text: 'Iron (%)',
                value: 'iron',
                sortable: false,
              },
            ],
            autofilterItems: [{
                name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                Retire: true,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                iron: 1,
              },
              {
                name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                Retire: true,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: 1,
              },
            ],
          }
        },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```